# java.io.EOFException using sstabledump

Tags: cassandra

I have a script that downloads all the necessary files to use sstabledump from gcloud and then dumps them to a json
but for some reason i got this error:

```
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readByte(RebufferingInputStream.java:180)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly(RebufferingInputStream.java:142)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readInt(RebufferingInputStream.java:222)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:157)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:132)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.Util.metadataFromSSTable(Util.java:317)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.main(SSTableExport.java:144)
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readByte(RebufferingInputStream.java:180)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly(RebufferingInputStream.java:142)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RebufferingInputStream.readInt(RebufferingInputStream.java:222)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:157)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.metadata.MetadataSerializer.deserialize(MetadataSerializer.java:132)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.Util.metadataFromSSTable(Util.java:317)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.main(SSTableExport.java:144)
```

any idea on why that could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That indicates to me that one (or more) of the SSTables is incomplete or corrupted.

The end-of-file exception (`EOFException`) gets thrown because the SSTable metadata indicates that there's more data in the `*-Data.db` file but the end of the file was reached.

This is expected if you are copying the files from the live `data/*` subdirectories because the files have not necessarily been (a) fully flushed to disk, or (b) not fully compacted yet.

I recommend that you do a `nodetool snapshot` and only copy the SSTables from the `snapshots/*` subdirectories to ensure that the files are fully consistent. Cheers!